# openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions in iOS 6 open two "connection systems" simultaneously

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using (trying to use...) the Facebook SDK for iOS 3.1.1 with iOS 6. When I check my app on iOS 5 simulator everything works fine. But when I try to open a session with openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions in iOS 6 i'm having one problem. Two things happen simultaneously:

1. Appears some system asking for permissions for the app: safari, the facebook app or iOS 6 integration. This part is okay. But...
2. Over the app appears a kind of popup where Facebook is asking us to connect to facebook. This second "screen" should't appear.

Someone knows why is it appearing?

I suppose there is something wrong on my project. Because I'm replicating this part in a new project and everything works fine.

Thanks a lot,

Carlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, very silly explanation. I was calling twice the methods to connect and publish in Facebook and then the application had "strange" behavior.